# Multi-valued parameter in SSRS 2008 isn't working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssrs-2008

I have a parameter `@Department` and set its value in the Dataset to `=Join(Parameters!Department.Value,",")`.  I set it to accept multiple values and in my SQL I have the following clause: `(RTRIM(G.DeptName) IN (@Department))`.

It works whenever the user selects one department, but doesn't work at all whenever multiple departments are selected.  It runs, but it doesn't display any data.  For example, if I select 'Accounting', it shows 'Accounting' info.  But if I select 'Accounting' and 'Marketing', nothing shows up.

Any ideas why this isn't working?  Also, is it possible to do this in this manner with something other than "string" values?

Comment: Can you post your query.

Comment: Why are you using the Join in your dataset? Multivalue parameters in SSRS should "just work" : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a false assumption.

`IN ('1,2,3,4')` is very different from `IN (1,2,3,4)` or `IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')`

What you are currently doing it the first one.  You are checking whether your department name is in a list which is only ***one*** value long; *the @department string*.  That value has commas in it, but it's still a single string, and so it's still a single item in the list.

You have two options.

Build up the SQL dynamically so that your list is part of the sql and not a string parameter.

Or look up one of the many `SPLIT()` function available on-line.  This is the one I recommend.  You can then do something like...

```
WHERE
  RTRIM(G.DeptName) IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.split(@Department))
```

Or even better, join on the results of the `SPLIT()` function...

```
  yourTable AS G
INNER JOIN
  dbo.split(@department) AS department
    ON  RTRIM(G.DeptName) = department.item
```

Comment: Just an extra note : If you have an index on `G.DeptName`, wrapping it in a function such as `RTRIM()` will mean that you can't use that index to *seek* the relevant records.  Instead you'll get a scan, making the index next to pointless.  If possible, store the value pre-trimmed, that way you don't need `RTRIM()` in your query, meaning you can use your index, and shorten your code :)

Answer (score 0):

As Dems said you need a join function for that.

you may use the one from here http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx

rest everything is fine with your query

```
WHERE
  RTRIM(G.DeptName) IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.split(@Department))
```

instead of `(RTRIM(G.DeptName) IN (@Department))`

should work.